# I want max volume of each datesection but when I run it show

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT
"public".steponesection.datesection,
"public".steponesection."Trade Price",
max ("public".steponesection."Trade Volume") OVER (partition by "public".steponesection.datesection) as max_Volm

FROM "public".steponesection)t

WHERE "public".steponesection."Trade Volume" = max_Volm
```

Results in this error:

```
[Err] ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "steponesection"
LINE 10: WHERE "public".steponesection."Trade Volume" = max_Volm

       ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear: the `where` clause cannot reference `steponesection` as on that level of the query there is no identifier with that name. The derived table is called `t` and that's what you need to use.

You also did not select the `"Trade Volume"` in the inner query, so it's not available in the outer level:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT "public".steponesection.datesection,
          "public".steponesection."Trade Price",
          "public".steponesection."Trade Volume",  --<< missing
           max ("public".steponesection."Trade Volume") OVER (partition by "public".steponesection.datesection) as max_volm
   FROM "public".steponesection
) t
WHERE t."Trade Volume" = t.max_volm --<< use the alias of the derived table
```

---

<sup>I would strongly recommend to avoid quoted identifiers like `"Trade Price"`. They are much more trouble in the long run then they are worth</sup>